# json parse have 2 different results?

Tags: jquery, json

Two pictures below is output from console, it has two different results in two different way when use console.log

[image]

pic 1 code

```
console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(this_.opts.data));
```

pic 2 code

```
this_.opts.data = jQuery.parseJSON(this_.opts.data);
console.log(this_.opts.data);
```

any idea?

Comment: Can you create any live demo of this ?

Comment: We don't know this_.opts.data value.Need demo to answer your question

Comment: Have you tried var a1 = jQuery.parseJSON(this_.opts.data);
console.log(a1);